# Cannot access oAuth2 of google apps api

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am getting the following error whenever I try to access `credential.refreshToken()`:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant" }
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:>103)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:303)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:323)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:340)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:508)
at com.intuit.dmx.storage.google.StorageAuthenticationServiceImpl.authenticateUser(StorageAut>henticationServiceImpl.java:51)
... 2 more
```

I am not getting this exception everytime. Sometimes it works fine, i.e. I can get the *access token*, sometimes it throws an exception.